# How to exit from a call stack in javascript

Tags: javascript, callstack

The alert happens twice, once inside the "dragover_handler" function and then again inside the addEventListener function for dragover.

[image: Call Stack in linebreak]
How to exit from the call stack after the first call? I have tried return, it does not work.

[Codepen Code](https://codepen.io/DPK_RAO/pen/xzQXjr)

below is the section of the code that has this alert

```
function dragover_handler(e) {
e = e || event;
e.preventDefault();

if(e.pageY < 24){        
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
  e.dataTransfer.dropEffect= "none";
     alert('You will be leaving this window'); 
  document.body.removeEventListener('dragover', function(e){
     this
  });
} else {
   e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
} 
 }

document.body.addEventListener('dragover', function(e){
dragover_handler(e);// return ;
}, false);
```

The code is in this link. First 'rightclick' - then click on add - then enter some text inside the input tag and click 'ok'. a div will be formed, drag that div upwards trying to pull it outside the window, when you reach the rim the alert has to appear - it has to happen just once

Comment: Could you post your code here for further examination? Posting images of code does not really help.

Comment: Please post the code as text.

Comment: Maybe you are adding event listeners twice, or forgetting to removeEventListener?

Comment: edited with link to code

Answer (score 0):

- you could use "dragenter" event instead of "dragover". It will fire only once when entering the target.
- or else, you could use removeEventListener inside your handler.

  ```
  const eventHandler = event => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("dragover", eventHandler)
      alert()
  }

  document.body.addEventListener("dragover", eventHandler)
  ```

Comment: dragenter also there, but dragover also required

Comment: document.body.removeEventListener('dragover', function(e){
         this
      });  - removed eventlisterner inside the handler, but still not working

Comment: remove the event then add alert is it?